# Wiring recessed lights with outlets in the same circuit

Tags: electrical, switch

Thanks for your help everyone!

I have a 3 gang switch box. power going to the switch 12/2. 1 switch controls the ceiling fan, the others controlled the ceiling lights. the 2 old lights in the ceiling  had 12/3 running to them and back into the switch. I have a couple outlets connected to this circuit. Im having trouble figuring out how to make the outlets live always. The power to these outlets was wiring into one of the old lights.s

Comment: You might have enough wires already installed to do this, but you need to post either a diagram or a very complete description of what type (e.g. 12/2, 12/3) of cable runs between which switch, light, and outlet junction boxes.

Comment: What do the three switches control? Is it one for the fan and one for each light?

Comment: What runs between the lights? A 12/2 or a 12/3?

Comment: The power for the outlets comes from which light? The one closest to the switches, or the one farthest from the switches?